# Mostrar Snack Bar con ScrollView

Tags: android

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un activity con un tab, dentro de este tab 2 fragment, el segundo con el Scroll, ya que los datos de este son varios hacia bajo, en el primero muestro el Snack bar con un mensaje. el problema es que el Snack Bar se muestra muy abajo ya que tiene todo el scroll. Es decir en el primer tab no se muestra, pero si cambio al segundo y bajo ahi esta el mensaje. Como puedo mostrar el snack bar en el primer tab en la aprte baja.

A continuacion el codigo xml:

FRAGMENT 1

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_dni"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_dni"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_dni"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_contrasena"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_contrasena"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_contrasena"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="5" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOlvidoSuContrasena"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/btn_olvido_su_contrasena"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnIniciarSesion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:text="@string/btn_iniciar_sesion"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <!--<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_or"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="O"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup_google"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:text="Iniciar Sesión con google"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup_facebook"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:text="Iniciar Sesión con facebook"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />-->

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar_resetear_contrasena"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

FRAGMENT 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:padding="@dimen/md_keylines">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_grande"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <!--  Nombres Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_nombres"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_nombres"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_nombres"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Apellido Materno Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_apellido_paterno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_apellido_paterno"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Apellido Paterno Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_apellido_materno"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_apellido_materno"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  DNI Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_dni"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_dni"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="8" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_correo_electronico"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_correo_electronico"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_contrasena"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/string_contrasena"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="4" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRegistrarse"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryColor"
            android:text="@string/btn_crear_cuenta"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <!--<TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member? Login"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_dot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <com.bhargavms.dotloader.DotLoader
        android:id="@+id/text_dot_loader"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextViewProgress"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:color_array="@array/dot_colors"
        app:dot_radius="4dp"
        app:number_of_dots="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registrando "
        android:textSize="44sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Orange_Resca"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

3 TAB CONTENEDOR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!-- <View
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:background="@color/white" />-->

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/iconogoogleplay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Lo normal es que el snack se muestra en la parte inferior de la pantalla pero como el segundo tab tiene un scroll el snack se va al ultimo y en el primer tab no se muestra.

CODIGO JAVA AL LLAMAR EL SNACK

```
snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.string_mensaje_de_sin_conexion), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    TextView textView = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                    snackbar.show();
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Podes agregar el codigo Java de como mostras el snack?